# Processing multiple checkbox in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, checkbox

I am not an expert with HTML and JavaScript. But here is what I am trying to do.

I have creating an HTML/jQuery/JS/CSS script.

The HTML file lists the number of files in the tabular form ( The number is not fixed) and I have checkboxes for each of the file.

The user can select one or more files to be deleted and click on "Submit" button.

Here is what I have tried :

- List all the files in the tabular column
- Include checkbox `<td><input type="checkbox" id="deletefile" /></td>`
- Submit button
- Prompt the user to confirm all the files
- I have written the code to delete the file in Python (I need to call the right URL to delete a single file)

I am not sure how to process all the checkbox entries in HTML/JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery you can get the input checkbox checked list by using the following code:

```
$('input:checked').each(function(i){
val[i] = $(this).val();
}
```

Here `val[i]` contains the array i.e., checked checkbox list so pass this array data to server-side code to delete from server.Hope this helps you :-)

EDIT:

Once check the live example below:

http://jsfiddle.net/rN2gm/

Select checkbox and click button after that again unselect and click.

Comment: Let me try with your approach. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Hi, What will happen if we check and uncheck it again ? The array entry is removed ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="deletefile[0]" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="deletefile[1]" /></td>
```

Use an array and you can identify each checkbox.

Comment: Hi. Thanks, I donot have the number of files as it is not fixed